# Sometimes got error while calling download api for recorded file from azure communication service

Tags: azure, azure-communication-services

I have created a meeting app with angular as front-end  and ASP.NET Core as back-end.  The application is working fine, but sometimes when I am trying to download the recorded file with servercallid, I am getting the error like **Service Unavailable**. But most of the time the file is generating and storing to blob storage.  But I do not know, why is getting error sometimes. We did not get any proper exception or reason as a response.

[image]

Do we have any specific size or timeframe constrain for generating the recorded file?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/concepts/voice-video-calling/call-recording#event-grid-notifications) recordings are only available to download for a limit amount of time:

> Azure Communication Services provides short term media storage for recordings. Recordings will be available to download for 48 hours. After 48 hours, recordings will no longer be available.

Comment: That is correct. I was trying to fetch the file immediately after stopping the recordings. After creating the recording file in ACS, the event grid will fire and call our API as web hook. This web hook api will fetch the recording file from acs and store to blob storage.